# play framework 2.0 How can I specify a different folder to run

Tags: playframework-2.0

I want to run play from a utility script which is not under the application's folder.

In play 1 you could write something like

```
play run  /my/path
```

however, I cannot find this option in play 2.0

keep getting :

```
This is not a play application!
```

I am also unable to find a manual for this command anywhere.

please help.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use `cd /my/path && play run && cd -` in your script?

Comment: Exact duplicate. And indeed, it would seem Casten's answer is the only solution for the moment.