# Play framework: App deployment in production: start app at specific folder on boot

Tags: java, bash, playframework, frameworks, startup

Usually, we start our Play framework applications by doing

```
cd /path/to/root/folder/of/app
play ~run
```

How can I start a play application without cd'ing into the directory where it is, like (this does not work):

```
play ~run /path/to/root/folder/of/app
```

I need this so I can start a play app on server startup, as a service.

I am using Play 2.2.3.

EDIT + ADD-UP:

As this became a duplicate of question [play framework 2.0 How can I specify a different folder to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739856/play-framework-2-0-how-can-i-specify-a-different-folder-to-run), I decided to reformulate to help people who want to start up a Play Framework app on boot up (using upstart on ubuntu), in production configuration. Just create another .conf file on the /etc/init directory of your server and paste this **(modify the file paths as needed)**.

```
description "myapp"
author      "jrocha"

# used to be: start on startup
# until we found some mounts werent ready yet while booting:
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on shutdown

# Automatically Respawn:
respawn
post-stop exec sleep 5

script
# Not sure why $HOME is needed, but we found that it is:
export HOME="/root"
cd /path/to/your/app && /play/play ~run >> /var/log/your_app_startup_log_file.log 2>&1 && cd -
end script

post-start script
#DO SOMETHING AFTER STARTING
echo "Play app started!"
end script
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739856/play-framework-2-0-how-can-i-specify-a-different-folder-to-run

Comment: Thanks for the comment, didnt find it before... however, i dont think it is the same problem, because the command needs to be able to go into an "exec" call. 

When i put it in the startup script, it gives me this...

/proc/self/fd/9: 4: exec: cd /dendro_recommender/dendro-researcher_panel_experiment && /play/play run && cd -: not found